# string to a char array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I have this code and I want to put the string I have in a char array in java, but the problem I have is whenever I use **toCharArray()** the array reduces its index so, what can I do to keep the array by the same original index?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "cat";
    char[][] carray;
    carray = new char[5][5];
    char[] chararray = new char[5];
    chararray = str.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        carray[i][0] = chararray[i];
    }
    System.out.println(carray);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        System.out.println("65"+carray[i][0]);
    }
```

Comment: What output are you getting? What do you expect?

Comment: if i keep the for loop                                                                          for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        carray[i][0] = chararray[i];
    }
to i<5 it gives me an error that it exceeds index
but if i make it i<3 it works fine

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add more information.... It's not really clear what you're trying to do. `toCharArray` doesn't alter index positions. And `cat` is only 3 letters, not 5. Plus, you do not need a `char[][]` to convert a string to a char array

Comment: this is an example or a small try out for a bigger project so i have a two dimensional array of char[][] but i also need to fill it from  a string that a user inserts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.charAt(i)` instead of `chararray[i]`

That may be help.

Comment: thank you that helped a lot instead of creating an array i can use this method and it solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

There are only three characters in "cat" (not five). Instead of hardcoding the length, use the `String` to determine the correct length. Also, your second array dimension should only be one (since you are only copying a single character at a time). Like,

```
String str = "cat";
char[] chararray = str.toCharArray();
char[][] carray = new char[chararray.length][1];
for (int i = 0; i < carray.length; i++) {
    carray[i][0] = chararray[i];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(carray));
for (int i = 0; i < carray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("65" + carray[i][0]);
}
```